# What's wrong with my MySQL update query?

Tags: php, mysql

I started learning php, I'm having some problems with this mysql query

```
  mysql_query( "UPDATE boardinfo SET totalPostCount = '" . $GLOBALS['postCount'] + 1 . "' WHERE boardName = '" . $_POST['board'] )
```

Error: near '1' WHERE boardName = 'Site' at line 1
All I need to do here is to update the value of totalPostCount if it's boardName matches value from $_POST['board']
Please, go easy on me, I've only started this yesterday...

Comment: You may not need the single quotes around your postcount since it's a number

Comment: There's no end `'` quote for boardname, and `==` isn't a standard operator in SQL, `=` is.

Comment: I put == there only just to see if that was the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your statement, quotes are not closed in last.

```
 mysql_query( "UPDATE boardinfo SET totalPostCount = '" .$GLOBALS['postCount'] + 1 . "' WHERE boardName = '" . $_POST['board']."'" )
```

If it doesn't solve your issue,try one more thing.

```
$val = $GLOBALS['postCount'] + 1;
mysql_query( "UPDATE boardinfo SET totalPostCount = '" .$val . "' WHERE boardName = '" . $_POST['board']."'" )
```

Hope it will solve your problem

Comment: Funny enough I tried the second option myself and it didn't work, yours did, now I got another syntax error but at least it's moving forward, thanks!

Comment: -1 Please do not post code vulnerable to SQL injection without any explanation what is wrong with it.

Comment: Hi dev-null-dweller, I'm still new to PHP and MYSQL and i would like to know how this is open to SQL injection? as i tend to use this kind of layout to update my databases (just being curious) :)